# using materialized views or alternatives in django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, database, postgresql

I need to use some `aggregate` data in my `django` application that changes frequently and if I do the calculations on the fly some performance issues may happen. Because of that I need to save the `aggregate` results in a table and, when data changes, update them. Because I use `django` some options may be exist and some maybe not. For example I can use `django signals` and a table that, when `post_save` signal is emitted, updates the results. Another option is `materialized views` in `postgresql` or `indexed views` in `MSSQL Server`, that I do not know how to use in `django` or if `django` supports them or not. What is the best way to do this in `django` for improving performance and accuracy of results.

Comment: You will probably have to use them via a rawsql query.

Comment: @wobbily_col how about using django signals or writing some functions for updating results?

Comment: The problem is that (as far as I am aware) you can't really map Django models to a materialised view. If you are using those in the database you are going to have to use raw sql to interact with them. If you are using functions, you are still going  to have to talk to the database somehow, either via the standard django ORM with models, or via raw sql. A more detailed description of what you are actually trying to achieve would be useful.

Comment: @wobbily_col i have three related tables which every one has a `number` field that when a new record added to one of these tables or `number` field of them get updated sum of `number` field in every table should be update for keeping balance. one of these tables has relation with user model and i need to keep user related activities (sum of `number` field) in track. i hope made my point. if you need any extra information let me know.

Comment: @wobbily_col you are right about using raw_sql or other ways but the problem is i want to find out the easiest and best way to do it.

Comment: Post your models in the question, so we have an idea of what they look like.

Comment: @Bartanix, in the case of MSSQL, the optimizer in Enterprise and Developer Editions will consider indexed views for query optimization even when only the base table(s) are referenced in queries.  Django need not even be aware than the indexed view exists.

Answer (score 14):

You can use Materialized view with postgres. It's very simple.

1. You have to create a view with query like `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW
   my_view as select * from my_table;`
2. Create a model with two
   option `managed=false` and `db_name=my_view` in the model `Meta` like
   this

   `MyModel(models.Model):
        class Meta:
               managed = False
               db_table='my_view'`
3. Simply use powers of ORM and treat MyModel as a regular model. e.g. `MyModel.objects.count()`

Comment: I've followed this method and it's worked for the most part. However, when setting setting a Foreign Key relationship or a OneToOne relationship from another model to the model attached to the View Table, I get the following error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: referenced relation "MaterializedViewTableName" is not a table`.

Comment: Refresh your views and try again. or share you create view query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PostgreSQL materialized view in Django to speed up complex SELECT queries with many JOIN operations. It helps a lot if you often have to perform in Django heavy `select_related` and `prefetch_related` operations.

At the same time, if you use PostgreSQL materialized view, queries that insert, update, or delete data will take longer and consume more computing resources. It makes sense to apply this technique if complex SELECT requests occur more often than data modifications.

The underlying data will change eventually. After that, you have to update the PostgreSQL materialized view somehow. It is essential to prevent users from getting stale cached data. To update the view, you can use the `save` method overriding in Django models, `post_save` and `m2m_changed` signals, or PostgreSQL database triggers.

Please see the detailed example of the Django PostgreSQL materialized view [in this repository](https://github.com/s-kust/django-postgresql-view). It contains the code that works, as well as explanations.

1. PostgreSQL materialized view in Django.
2. `EagerLoadingMixin` in Django REST framework serializer classes to
   solve the N+1 queries problem.
3. Usage of the most generic `viewsets.ModelViewSet` to build views in
   Django REST framework fast and easy.
4. Advanced PostgreSQL SQL Query with several Common Table Expressions
   and JSON functions.
5. Django `post_save` and `m2m_changed` signals.
6. Populating the Django database with fake generated data for testing.